# Cordova iOS cannot disable Keyboard Shrinks View

Tags: ios, cordova

With latest Cordova on iOS 8.1, it seems I cannot prevent the keyboard to shrink the view height.

I've tried the following settings:

- in my config.xml:

  ```
  <preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="false" />
  ```
- in the index.html viewport tag:

  `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />`

  or

  `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />`

  or

  `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />`

None of these disabling the shrink behavior.

How could I prevent the keyboard from shrinking the view on iOS?

Comment: Hey! Did you found any successful answer to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing a very different problem. I can't get cordova to resize the webview like it used to anymore ^^.

with regards to 
`<preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="false" />`
This is disregarded on ios7 and higher in the **org.apache.cordova.labs.keyboard** plugin.

The code states:

```
// No-op on iOS7.  It already resizes webview by default, and this plugin
// is causing layout issues
// with fixed position elements.  We possibly should attempt to implement 
// shrinkview = false on iOS7.
if (!IsAtLeastiOSVersion(@"7.0")) { ... }
```

I suspect the culprit/savior is in the meta tag. That's where I'm going to look.

Currently mine looks like this:

```
'<meta name="viewport" content="width=' + viewPortWidth + ', user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1' + extra + '"/>'
```

where `viewPortWidth` is dependent on the device, in case of an iphone it's 320, and `extra` is `target-densityDpi=device-dpi` in case it's android

Hope it can help you a bit

Comment: So the only difference you have is that your viewport has ```target-densityDpi=device-dpi```. I've tried it and it did not change anything... Are you sure your window height doesn't change when the keyboard is up ?

Comment: My problem is that I need my window height to shrink, so that the input field that is positioned at bottom:0; isn't below the keyboard.

Comment: Just to clarify. I'm not talking about page scrolling down. I'm talking about actually re-sizing the view, so anything that is absolute positioned at the bottom, would stick to the keyboard, and anything absolute positioned at the top, would still stay at the top. If you are referring to avoiding the scrolling there are ways for that.

Comment: Are you really sure your window.innerHeight doesn't get shrunk when the keyboard is up ? Are you talking about iOS too ?

Comment: Yes, I'm even checking the webView in the debugger before and after the keyboard shows. The webview and the scrollview are the same height as before. I ended up doing a hack, where I change the height of the view manually on keyboardWillShow. I doubt it will help your situation at all though. The hack was, that I outcommented the "isAtLeastiOSVersion" check. This has some adverse effects on the layout though, but it seems it's something we will have to live with.

Comment: @AskeG - how did you get IOS to shrink again?

Comment: @digger69 - I used the org.apache.cordova.labs.keyboard plugin, and commented out the isAtLeastiOSVersion(@"7.0") in the shrinkingView function to allow for the shrinking to occur again on iOS8. However, there is a problem with the size of the scrolling view (I suspect this is the culprit for the if-statement) that I had to fix as best as possible. I have to admit that in the end I never quite understood the interaction that the auto-layout has, and I suspect there is a problem with the fact that I am also removing the AccesoriesBar from the keyboard.

Comment: Interesting... the comment for that line is "No-op on iOS7.  It already resizes webview by default, and this plugin is causing layout issues with fixed position elements.  We possibly should attempt to implement shringview = false on iOS7." So, something must have changed. Sounds like a PR is in order.

ah, there is one : https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/pull/18